# Computed Column in SQL server 2008 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I create a computed column like the following table??

```
ID Group Name Age myComputedColumn
-----------------------------------
1  001   FF   28  00
2  001   GG   29  01
3  001   II   35  02
4  002   AA   15  00
5  001   UU   26  03
6  002   BB   17  01
7  002   CC   15  02
```

In `myComputedColumn`, I would like to have value starting at `'00'` up to `'24'`, after the row reaches '24', then it will create a new number which is '00' until '24'

How can I create a computed column like this? Or maybe I need to create a function when inserting a new record?

Thank you.

Comment: what basis computed column calculated ?

Comment: You can't create a computed column that does this but you can certainly select it out as in the example answers below.

Comment: ok thank you, so how can I implement the answer into "Insert" syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the number to go from 0 to 24, then you would use:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (partition by [group] order by id) - 1) % 25
from table t;
```

The `%` operator is the modulus operator.  It returns the remainder after integer division.

To get this as a character, the `right()`/append `0` trick works fine:

```
select t.*,
       right('0' + cast((row_number() over (partition by [group] order by id) - 1) % 25 as varchar(3)), 2) as ComputedColumn
from table t;
```

Comment: I tried your last syntax, but the compcolumn, start from 0, 1, 2, ff. Should be 00, 01, 02, ff.

Comment: @Haminteu . . . A `cast()` is needed to make the string logic work.

Answer (score 1):

This will give value statrting from 1,2,3 and so on..

```
Select ID,Group,Name,Age,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY ID) as computedcolumn
FROM tableName
```

You can change if want to start from zero , subtract by 1

```
Select ID,Group,Name,Age,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY ID) - 1 as computedcolumn
FROM tableName
```

Ok , so you want padded zeros also , you can do using RIGHT()

```
Select ID,Group,Name,Age,
       RIGHT('0' + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY ID) - 1 , 2) as computedcolumn
FROM tableName
```

Comment: is it sql server 2012 syntax?

Comment: it is compatible for 2005+ , ie all version 2005 onwards ..2005,2008,2012

Comment: on your last syntax, i tried that one.. But the result of the computedcolumn is start from 0, 1, 2, 3, ff. it should be, 00, 01, 02, 03, ff.